# Move to Rails 5.1 Unexpected token: eof (undefined) in move to Production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, exec, eof, precompile

I'm having problems moving a Rails app that I've updated from 4.x to 5.1 into production.  Works fine in development, but when I use Capistrano to move to the production environment, I get the below. Note that every post of similar issues seems to have a syntax error in their code, and while it is possible (quite ; ) I do too, I don't see a reference below to MY js code, only "library" code. Unless the 3528:621 is to a concatenated file for my code? Anyway, I precompile the assets in development, seems to work fine.  Any suggestions on how to ferret this out?

Update a few minutes later: IN FACT SAME PROBLEM WHEN I COMPILE IN DEV!  sorry. Now, what's the easiest way to find out what line this is?

```
deployer@new-apoxeia:~/apps/apoxeia_production/releases/20180101152401$ RAILS_ENV=production RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.4.2 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace 
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)
JS_Parse_Error.Object.defineProperty.get ((execjs):3538:621)
(execjs):4060:47
(execjs):1:102
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
Module.load (module.js:344:32)
Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
startup (node.js:136:18)
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:195:in `run_uglifyjs'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:157:in `compile'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/apps/apoxeia_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling `uglifier`? Do you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I just went thru all my javascript, disabling half, then the other half, and then when I got to the file, did the same thing. Took awhile, but I found the offending line, removed it, and everything is OK. (Well, with that problem ; )

Derek - Thanks for the support, but I found the problem.  Have great day!